# How To Get Information From Discord User ID / Name Even If The User Is Not Within The Server In Discord Python

Tags: python, discord.py

I currently wanna make a discord bot that needs information from user inside ( and outside ) the server

> I have a few discord id and discord user i wanna get informations from like
>   profile picture,current username,last online,and online status

i have found the following website https://discord.id/ however it has recaptcha so i can't really use it for my bot however i'm curious as to how the website is able to grab those data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
await client.fetch_user(user.id)
```

Comment: how would i get their current status like if they're online,offline,idle,do not disturb and offline ?

Comment: No, because in documentation, this is user, not member. On member you can look who is online/offline/on PC/on phone etc.